# How Can I read a string from a txt file line by line and run it with a function?

Tags: python, double, line, func, letter

I have a txt file named `a.txt`. In this file a has a string per line. I want to append these strings line by line to the `keyword = {}` dict and run my `double_letter` function for each line of string. How can I do it?

my double_letter function:

```
keyword = {}

def double_letter():
    print("\nDouble Letter:\n")
    idx = random.randint(0, len(keyword) - 1)
    keyword = keyword[:idx] + keyword[idx] + keyword[idx:]
    print(keyword)
```

Comment: In your function would the variable `keyword `be the string that you want repeated at a random letter?  If so, why did you declare it a global variable (only for special cases) rather than as an argument to the function (the usual method)?

Comment: @DarrylG Can you check again ?. I edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You can open, read and print the contents of a txt file as follows:

```
f = open("a.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

You can add in your function for each run through the for loop, i.e. calling it during each line of the text:

```
f = open("a.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    print(line)
    double_letter()
```

Comment: This only works for keyword = "family" variable. Can you check again?

Comment: When I posted the answer, there was no additional information about your `keyword` dictionary; can you clarify more? You have it as an empty dictionary - do you want the lines of the txt file to be added as keys? values? etc.

Comment: They will all be strings. There will be one string per line. I want to throw these strings in the txt file into the `keyword = {}` dict. And after assigning the dict I want to run the function for each string.

Comment: You would need to add a key/value pair to a dictionary, rather than a single string. It is not entirely clear what your desired output/goal is to me now. What would this dictionary look like after running? You've also named the empty dictionary `keyword` and within your function you are reassigning something to that variable name.

Comment: How can I do if I want the `double_letter` function to run for each line in the txt file? Example txt: `(first line) family`, `(second line) soccer`

Comment: You need to clarify what you would like the dictionary to look like afterwards. What are your intended keys and values?

Comment: I just want the output from the `double_letter` to appear.

Comment: If your txt file contains "apple", "banana", would you like the dictionary to look like {"apple" : "applee", "banana" : "bbanana"} as an example? At the moment, your function will always print something to do with the word soccer, no matter what is in your text file. Also, your function doesn't return any values/strings to be used, it only prints.

Comment: I just want the `value` result. I mean; `"banana": "bannana"`. I just want `value(bannana)`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

**Code**

```
import random

def double_letter(line):
    '''
        Repeats random letter in line
    '''
    if line:
        idx = random.randint(0, len(line) - 1)
        return line[:idx] + line[idx] + line[idx:]
    else:
        return line     # does nothing with blank lines
    
with open("a.txt", "r") as f:                # with preferred with open file
    keyword = {}                             # setup results dictionary
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()                 # remove the '\n' at the end of each line
        keyword[line] = double_letter(line)  # add line with it's repeat to dictionary
        
print(keyword)
```

**File a.txt**

```
Welcome
To
Stackoverflow
```

**Output**

```
{'Welcome': 'Welcomee', 'To': 'Too', 'Stackoverflow': 'Stackoverfloow'}
```